# Characters are not escaped properly in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string such as this:

```
Hello[00]
```

And I want to replace the [00] with 00 (I don't want to do it through deleting the [] because that won't be useful for me later). I want a direct replace from [00] to 00. To do so, I have the following code:

```
            var conversionRegex = new Regex(string.Join("|", conversion.Keys));
            var textConverted = conversionRegex.Replace(allLines, n => conversion[n.Value]);
```

"conversion" is a Dictionary [string],[string]. And one of its entries is this one:

```
{@"\[00\]","00"}
```

According to my knowledge and experience, that should work properly, but it isn't. It throws an exception: the key can't be found in the dictionary. However, when the exception is thrown, the debugger says that "n.Value" equals to "[00]". So it should be found in the dictionary, because it's there!

I have more elements in this Dictionary, but the only ones that are throwing exceptions are the ones with characters that should be escaped. Somehow they are not escaped properly...

Any ideas on this? Thank you very much!

Comment: If you use `@`, you should not need to escape anything in a string (except `"`), so try `@"[00]"`.

Comment: The constructor for Regex(new Regex()) want a pattern not the keys.

Comment: Also, `[` and `]` don't even need to be escaped. So just use `"[00]"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing escaping for regex with escaping for C# string literals.  Square brackets ([]) have no special meaning in C# string literals and thus do not need to be escaped.  However, they do have special meaning in regex so they do need to be escaped in the regex string if you wish to match those chars.  Your key is properly escaped for regex but that means your C# string literal contains literal backslash chars.

Here is how C# interprets the following string literals:

- "[00]" is a 4-char string containing the chars [00].
- "\[00\]" is invalid C# due to invalid \[ and \] C# string literal escape sequences.  It will not compile.
- @"\[00\]" is a 6-char string containing the chars \[00\]. This is the proper format for escaping for regex but it's important to recognize that the backslashes are part of the C# string literal and not C# escape sequences.  This will not match "[00]" because they are different strings.
- "\\[00\\]" is the same as the previous.  Instead of using @, it uses the C# \\ escape sequence which emits a literal backslash char.

When you use @"\[00\]" as a dictionary key, your dictionary key includes those 
backslash chars.  Therefore, your dictionary does not contain the key "[00]".

There are a few different ways you could rewrite your code to accomplish what you are trying to do.  Here's an easy way to do by using the string representation without the regex escaping as the dict keys and then using Regex.Escape to escape these for generating the regex string.

```
var conversion = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { @"[00]", "00" }
};

var allLines = "Hello[00]\r\nWorld[00]";
var conversionRegex = new Regex(string.Join("|", conversion.Keys.Select(key => Regex.Escape(key))));
var textConverted = conversionRegex.Replace(allLines, n => conversion[n.Value]);
Console.WriteLine(textConverted);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. And thanks for explaining everything. It was really helpful.